# Sorting key value pairs in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, sorting

I have a large file containing inventories in this format:

```js
$inventories = {"External Hard Drives":2,"Cables":1,"Disks":10,"Floppy Drives":1,"USB Sticks":5}`
```

I am trying to sort these by the value of each, in ascending order. I have tried:

`arsort($inventories)` and `array_sort(inventories)` without success. Any help please? I am working in Laravel 5.6.

Comment: `$inventories = {"External Hard Drives":2,"Cables":1,"Disks":10,"Floppy Drives":1,"USB Sticks":5}`. PHP doesn't support this kind of syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. `array_sort` does not support object, but array.

```
$inventories = '{"External Hard Drives":2,"Cables":1,"Disks":10,"Floppy Drives":1,"USB Sticks":5}';
```

Now decode it with 2nd parameter `true` to transform into associative array.

```
$inventories = json_decode($inventories, true); // now you have array
```

Then you can do it your own way :

```
$inventories = array_sort($inventories); // this works
```

Or Use Laravel Collections approach (https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-sort) that transforms auto for you :

```
$inventories = collect($inventories);
$inventories = $inventories->sort();
```

`echo json_encode($inventories);` will print :

```
{
    Cables: 1,
    Floppy Drives: 1,
    External Hard Drives: 2,
    USB Sticks: 5,
    Disks: 10
}
```

Do fancy comparison with 2 values :

```
$inventories = $inventories->sort(function($v1, $v2) {
    return $v2 > $v1;
});
```

This will print reverse :

```
{
    Disks: 10,
    USB Sticks: 5,
    External Hard Drives: 2,
    Cables: 1,
    Floppy Drives: 1
}
```

Laravel sort uses `uasort` in background, so you can use them directly too, but only with array as input.

Answer (score 0):

Once you read your file you could do something like

```
$inventories = '{"External Hard Drives":2,"Cables":1,"Disks":10,"Floppy Drives":1,"USB Sticks":5}';

collect(json_decode($inventories))->sort();
```

Output

```
=> Illuminate\Support\Collection {#2968
     all: [
       "Cables" => 1,
       "Floppy Drives" => 1,
       "External Hard Drives" => 2,
       "USB Sticks" => 5,
       "Disks" => 10,
     ],
   }
```